# Создание объекта и вызов метода в одной строке PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите как правильнее оформить функцию: создавать объект и вызывать метод в одной строке или разделить?
Понимаю, что можно любым способом, но как будет правильнее? Возможно что-то считается дурным тоном.
Для короткой функции, которая выполняет только одно действие есть ли смысл делить на строки и создавать несколько переменных?

**Метод 1:**

```
public function Sort()
{
    (new Drugs(Request::getObject('db')))->updateDrugsSorting($_POST);
}
```

**Метод 2:**

```
public function Sort()
{
    $db = Request::getObject('db');
    $Drugs = new Drugs($db);
    $Drugs->updateDrugsSorting($_POST);
}
```

Comment: ...Вкусовщина...

Comment: Я бы скорее делал так: если нужно сделать одно действие - то однострочник, если больше одного или билдер - то разделял бы (это я имел в виду по поводу Drugs.....). Нужно всё же ориентироваться на читабельность кода.

Comment: Я не знаю ни одного стандарта, который определял бы такое поведение. Но чисто субъективно, мне второй вариант нравится больше.

Comment: У меня к этому коду будут другие замечания. 1. Совершенно непонятно, что делает объект `'db'` в репозитории `Request`. Я бы скорее ожидал, что в нем будут содержаться данные НТТР запроса. 2. Почему переменная, с которой работает метод `updateDrugsSorting()` берется из воздуха, что нарушает чуть ли не все принципы SOLID разом. Ну и, собственно, к `$db` та же претензия. Зависимости в коде желательно прописывать явно, что значительно облегчит отладку, тестирование и повторное использование кода.

Comment: К сожалению, я самоучка, учился по книгам котерова ещё в 2005 году. Я не знаю, где вообще хранить эту бд, чтобы не передавать ее в каждый контролёр, а из контроллера в модель, чтобы каждый раз не создавать объект db. Для этого создал класс контейнер, где на главной странице где идёт соединение с бд сохраняю, а затем получаю этот объект методом getObject. Не совсем понял, про какую переменную, которая берется из воздуха идёт речь $Drugs? А как её ещё создать? Сильно не пинайте, работаю бесплатно исключительно для сообщества, где могу черпаю информацию. Естественно нет никаких менторов

Comment: Какую тему почитать, чтобы понять, как это делать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Форматирование кода зависит от нескольких факторов:

1. Стандарты разработки, принятые в компании, где вы работаете
2. Возможность легко изменить код, добавить или удалить фрагменты.
3. Если функция атомарная (ВСЕГДА делает только одно действие, не принимает параметров или параметр ВСЕГДА только ОДИН, вероятность модификации вызова минимальна), то желательно однострочное оформление.
4. Личные предпочтения.

ПС. Мне больше нравится второй вариант.

Comment: Ещё один пункт кстати, легкость чтения диффов. И в этом смысле второй вариант также предпочтительнее